# org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic <Topic Name> not present in metadata after 60000 ms

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to connect Kinesis to Kafka using apache flink. I was able to create Kafka topic. I have the kinesis stream but when I try to run my application it errors with the following error.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic <Topic Name> not present in metadata after 60000 ms
```

Comment: Could you point me to the API you are using for Kinesis for Scala, there are some configurations in libraries that will auto create topics if not exists example: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connectconfigs_topic.creation.enable

Answer (score 0):

This simply means your connection is not authenticated to list topics, or the client cannot connect to Kafka given the values you've specified.